# Which role is attached to instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-cli

How to **check which IAM roles and it's policy json, are attached to the running EC2** instance?

Is it possible through AWS CLI?

Here the response for aws ec2 ddescribe-instances
[image]

I tried firing the command - **aws iam list-instance-profiles**, 
it gave me the following error - 
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListInstanceProfiles operation: User: is not authorized to perform: iam:ListInstanceProfiles on resource:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. If you look at the response generated by [`aws ec2 describe-instances`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html) command, you'll notice that the resulting JSON data has

> ### `IamInstanceProfile` -> (structure)
>
> The IAM instance profile associated with the instance, if applicable.
>
> #### `Arn` -> (string)
>
> The Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the instance profile.
>
> #### `Id` -> (string)
>
> The ID of the instance profile.

And later, you can use the [`iam` cli interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/get-instance-profile.html) to fetch policy/role details.

```
aws iam get-instance-profile --instance-profile-name <name here>
```

Comment: Do I need any role attached to the EC2 instance in order to fetch these details?

Comment: I am referring this link - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/get-instance-profile.html , What instance-profile-name value do I pass? Where do I get the info?

Comment: @AniruddhaRaje I do not have any instance attached to any IAM profile. Can you put the output of your `describe-instance` command in the question?

Comment: I tried firing the command - aws iam list-instance-profiles, it gave me the following error-> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListInstanceProfiles operation: User: is not authorized to perform: iam:ListInstanceProfiles on resource:

Comment: @AniruddhaRaje Specifically the `IamInstanceProfile` section. And that error means that your organisation has not allowed you access to the IAM resources in AWS. Ask your AWS admin to grant iam policies to your user.

Comment: I have complete IAM access, I have now 2 policies attached to the role I created IAMFullAccess and AmazonS3FullAccess. which particular IAM policy should I ask them?

Comment: @AniruddhaRaje Apparently, you do not have access to `describe-instances` command either. Please check with the AWS admin whether your access keys have been activated or not.

Comment: @hjpotter92: How to achieve the same using boto3/python?

Comment: @Drew https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances

Answer (score 10):

No need to look for AWS CLI installed your Machine, Just machine should have internet and no block from metadata.
You can curl the metadata from EC2:

```
curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/info |grep InstanceProfileArn  | awk '{print $3}'
```

Answer (score 3):

Please run describe-instances command (OSX/Linux/UNIX) to determine whether the selected instance has any IAM Roles/Instance Profiles assigned:

```
  aws ec2 describe-instances
    --region us-east-1
    --instance-ids i-07a2ad8872fb3226b
    --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].IamInstanceProfile'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [boto3](/questions/tagged/boto3) (Python):

```
import boto3    
client = boto3.client('ec2')

response = client.describe_instances()

# Example 1 - Short version
for r in response['Reservations']:
  for instance in r['Instances']:
    if instance.get('IamInstanceProfile'):
      print (instance['InstanceId'], instance['IamInstanceProfile'])



# Example 2 - Longer version    
for r in response['Reservations']:
  for instance in r['Instances']:
    if instance.get('IamInstanceProfile'):
      raw = client.describe_iam_instance_profile_associations(
        Filters=[
            {
                'Name': 'instance-id',
                'Values': [instance['InstanceId']]
            }
        ]
      )
      current_res = raw.get('IamInstanceProfileAssociations')[0] # <----- We're passing only one instance id in filter so only one result is returned
      print (current_res.get('InstanceId'), current_res.get('IamInstanceProfile'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using boto3

```
ec2 = session.client('ec2') 
iam = session.client('iam')
```

Describe the instance profile association using ec2 client and fetch the instance profile name

```
ec2.describe_iam_instance_profile_associations(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-id','Values': ['i-02a1cde71XXXXXX']}])
```

Response:

```
{'IamInstanceProfileAssociations': [{'AssociationId': 'iip-assoc-0f7dd8ceeXXXXXX', 'InstanceId': 'i-02a1cde71XXXXXX', 'IamInstanceProfile': {'Arn': 'arn:aws:iam::12345679012:instance-profile/XYZ', 'Id': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'}, 'State': 'associated'}],....... }
```

Use iam client and do get_instance_profile call to get the RoleName associated with the instanceProfile

```
iam.get_instance_profile(InstanceProfileName='XYZ')
```

Response:

```
{'InstanceProfile': {'Path': '/', 'InstanceProfileName': 'XYZ', 'InstanceProfileId': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'Arn': arn:aws:iam::12345679012:instance-profile/XYZ', 'CreateDate': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 10, 16, 15, 8, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'Roles': [{'Path': '/', 'RoleName': 'ABCD', ............... 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

Optionally you can use list_attached_role_policies to know what are the managed policy attached with the role

```
iam.list_attached_role_policies(RoleName='ABCD')
```

Response:

```
{'AttachedPolicies': [{'PolicyName': 'EFG', 'PolicyArn': 'arn:aws:iam::12345679012:policy/EFG'}], 'IsTruncated': ......}}
```